# Find the path of an exported csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, path

I have a function
`foo(file_path)`
that takes in the file_path of a file.

After writing a dataframe to a csv file,

`df.to_csv("df.csv" , index = False)`

How do I get this recently exported csv's path? So that I can pass it into my function

Comment: "df.csv" is the path of the csv relative to the directory the script is executed in.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I wish to pass the csv's file path into a function. Is there a way to do this without directly checking my directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already pointed out in the comments -- you already possess the path, "to_csv" does not make it up.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

> **path_or_bufstr or file handle**, default None
>
> **File path** or object, if None is provided the result is returned as a string. If a file object
>   is passed it should be opened with newline=’’, disabling universal
>   newlines. Changed in version 0.24.0: Was previously named “path” for
>   Series.

If you need an absolute file path, that's another question, here is how you can have it:

```
import pandas
import os

test = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
        'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']}

df = pandas.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b'])

path = "data.csv"
full_path = os.path.abspath(path)  # get the FULL path

print(f'{path} -> {full_path}')

df.to_csv(path)
```